# Should I reserve memory when using std::back_inserter

Tags: c++, std, c++98

Do I need to reserve memory when using a back:inserter?

```
d.reserve(s.size())
std::copy (s.begin(),s.end(),back_inserter(d));
```

Comment: Note: the actual performance gain of reserving memory can be quite tiny, in average you avoid one copy per element (yes, just one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to reserve memory for the container when using `std::back_inserter`. However, if you know beforehand about the number of elements you are going to insert and want to prevent repeated allocations you may reserve memory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. However, if this code snippet is run very frequently, you may consider reserving memory to improve performance.